# jmeter removes slash (/) from requested URL's

Tags: jmeter, slash

I requested a web page using Jmeter with "Retrieve all embedded resources" enabled. When I ran the scenario, some URLs' of pictures did not open with the error "Bad Request". When I compared the working URL and URL that Jmeter checks, I realized that / is missing on the URL that Jmeter checks.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYAFq.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ngq4.png)

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Don't put http:// in path, can you show how HTTP request look in JMeter?

Comment: We don't add "http://" in path but system does, just like pictures located at http://thumbor.org/. To illustrate, the path of one picture from thumbor is:

http://s2.glbimg.com/yP1cwBSy2i3Welt_RjHj38e4GlY=/720x350/smart/http://s.glbimg.com/en/ho/static/thumbor/why-thumbor-1.jpg

Comment: you can Click Ctrl+G in HTTP Request and show how it defined?

Comment: I put it as Screenshot2 above. I changed Server Name or IP to thumbor.org as an example.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in JMeter.

You should submit a bug following this doc:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html

Ensure you attach:
- the HTML page content that contains the links
- The jmeter.log
- A sample test plan

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same with the version 2.13. No problem, which means that version 3.3 is buggy in terms of this issue.

Comment: Why don't you submit a bug issue as proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47932091/460802 ? Don't you want it to be fixed in next version ? Also your answer looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/47932091/460802. Thanks